# How to limit the input in DateTime picker?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, datetime

I am making a django app which is going to collect data from a form. In the form I'm gonna put some normal fields and a DateTime field, but I wanna limit that DateTime field so the user can only select:

1. For the Date:

   - from today to lets say 1 year ahead
2. For the Time:

   - from the current local time(so if the date is today, they won't be able to pick a time before the current local time)
   - afterwards every day from 10:00 until 21:00

Is there a way to do that? Thank You!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do backend validation in django by using the model's `clean` method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

If you want a better user experience, you need to do that with javascript. The way you solve it there depends on the tool you use. (e.g. jquery Datepicker?)
This validates the input before you submit the form to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know how to validate the input, but I want to maybe "gray out" the unavailable dates, so the user couldn't choose them at all.